# Power function giving different answer than math.pow function in C

Tags: c, pow, math.h

I was trying to write a program to calculate the value of x^n using a `while` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 3, power = 1, copyx;
    int n = 22, copyn;
    copyx = x;
    copyn = n;

    while (n)
    {
        if ((n % 2) == 1)
        {
            power = power * x;
        }
        n = n / 2;
        x *= x;
    }

    printf("%g^%d = %f\n", copyx, copyn, power);
    printf("%g^%d = %f\n", copyx, copyn, pow(copyx, copyn));

    return 0;
}
```

Up until the value of 15 for `n`, the answer from my created function and the `pow` function (from `math.h`) gives the same value; but, when the value of `n` exceeds 15, then it starts giving different answers.

I cannot understand why there is a difference in the answer. Is it that I have written the function in the wrong way or it is something else?

Comment: Use `double` (which has more precision) instead of `float`. But you'll run into the same problem for larger numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up two different types of floating-point data. The `pow` function uses the `double` type but your loop uses the `float` type (which has less precision).

You can make the results coincide by *either* using the `double` type for your `x`, `power` and `copyx` variables, *or* by calling the `powf` function (which uses the `float` type) instead of `pow`.

The latter adjustment (using `powf`) gives the following output (clang-cl compiler, Windows 10, 64-bit):

```
3^22 = 31381059584.000000
3^22 = 31381059584.000000
```

And, changing the first line of your `main` to `double x = 3, power = 1, copyx;` gives the following:

```
3^22 = 31381059609.000000
3^22 = 31381059609.000000
```

Note that, with larger and larger values of `n`, you are increasingly likely to get divergence between the results of your loop and the value calculated using the `pow` or `powf` library functions. On my platform, the `double` version gives the same results, right up to the point where the value overflows the range and becomes `Infinity`. However, the `float` version starts to diverge around `n = 55`:

```
3^55 = 174449198498104595772866560.000000
3^55 = 174449216944848669482418176.000000
```

Comment: Re "*the float version starts to diverge around n = 55:*", Since an float has around 7 digits of precision, it's pretty surprising it only diverged for numbers that large! (I'm assuming a `float` is an IEEE single-precision floating point number, as found in x86 and x86-64.) Note that the result are the same to 7 digits of precision. The two number are probably 1 one away from each other.

Comment: @ikegami Yes - I was also surprised. However, the actual calculations in the loop are performed on *promoted* (to `double`) values and, further, the 'accumulated' values are ever-increasing, so loss of precision in the lower bits of the significands are probably not that critical.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianMole for your answer. But can you please give a short explanation of how the precision is lost in the lower bits for a `float` value?

Answer (score 3):

When I run your code I get this:

```
3^22 = 31381059584.000000
3^22 = 31381059609.000000
```

This would be because `pow` returns a `double` but your code uses `float`. When I changed to `powf` I got identical results:

```
3^22 = 31381059584.000000
3^22 = 31381059584.000000
```

So simply use `double` everywhere if you need high resolution results.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point math is imprecise (and `float` is worse than `double`, having even fewer bits to store the data in; using `double` might delay the imprecision longer). The `pow` function (usually) uses an exponentiation algorithm that minimizes precision loss, and/or delegates to a chip-level instruction that may do stuff more efficiently, more precisely, or both. There could be more than one implementation of `pow` too, depending on whether you tell the compiler to use strictly conformant floating point math, the fastest possible, the hardware instruction, etc.

Your code is fine (though using `double` would get more precise results), but matching the improved precision of `math.h`'s `pow` is non-trivial; by the time you've done so, you'll have reinvented it. That's why you use the library function.

That said, for logically integer math as you're using here, precision loss from your algorithm likely doesn't matter, it's purely the `float` vs. `double` issue where you lose precision from the type itself. As a rule, default to using `double`, and only switch to `float` if you're *100%* sure you don't need the precision and can't afford the extra memory/computation cost of `double`.

Answer (score 1):

**Precision**

`float x = 3, power = 1; ... power = power * x` forms a `float` product.

`pow(x, y)` forms a `double` result and good implementations internally use even wider math.

OP's loop method incurs rounded results after the 15th iteration.  These roundings slowly compound the inaccuracy of the final result.

3<sup>16</sup> is a 26 bit odd number.

`float` encodes all odd numbers exactly until typically 2<sup>24</sup>.  Larger values are all even and of only 24 significant binary digits.

`double` encodes all odd numbers exactly until typically 2<sup>53</sup>.

---

To do a fair comparison, use:

- `double` objects and `pow()` or
- `float` objects and `powf()`.

For large powers, the `pow(f)()` function is certain to provide better answers than a loop at such functions often use internally extended precision and well managed rounding vs. the loop approach.